# perl: replacing a list of substrings by another list

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I have a first file `file1` containing a string `All cars are red.` I want to replace a list of words (`list1`) from the initial string `cars red` by another list of words `list2` containing `boats blue` to get this output

```
All boats are blue.
```

The goal here is to do that with a bigger list of words to be replaced and on a bigger string with multiple occurence of words to be replaced.

I guess the code should look something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open (my $list1, "<", "list1.txt") or die "cannot open list1\n";
open (my $list2, "<", "list2.txt") or die "cannot open list2\n";
open (my $file1, "<", "file1.txt") or die "cannot open file1\n";

my @replacer = <$list2>;
my @tobereplaced = <$list1>;

foreach my $word (@replacer) {
my $file1 =~ s/$tobereplaced/$word/gee; }
```

Could someone help me get the desired output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@tobereplaced = map split, @tobereplaced;
@replacer     = map split, @replacer;

my %replacements;
@replacements{@tobereplaced} = @replacer;

my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, @tobereplaced;
my $re = qr/$pat/;

while (<$file1>) {
   s/\b($re)\b/$replacements{$1}/g;
   print;
}
```

You didn't specify the format of the input files, so I had to do some guessing.

Comment: Fixed. So used to seeing the things to search first.

Comment: don't you have to actually read the file? Something like `while (<$file1>) { s/\b($pat)\b/$replacements{$1}/g; print; }`

Comment: it now returns this "GLOB(0x6000701d8)"

Comment: You were treating `$file1` as the contents of the file, so I did the same. But it's a file handle, so I've adjusted my accordingly.